# On-premises file synchronization with upload approval workflow

Tags: file-synchronization, workflow, active-directory

I am looking for a on premises (open source or commercial) file sharing solution for our company.

Our administrators have two computers, one for server administration and another for regular email/internet use.

At times the administrators will need to copy files to the server (scripts, agents, etc) and other times copy files from servers (troubleshooting logs, etc)

As of now they are copying files from the server to their administration system and the copying to the regular system via Windows File Share. This raises the issue of data leakage. 
Also the same is the case to copy files to the server (raises the issue for malicious content and unauthorized files being copied to servers)

So we ended up looking for solution for file sharing that has the below

- Individual accounts for administrators to upload/download their files
- Handle large file uploads (1GB)
- Handle multiple file upload
- Active directory integration
- Anti-virus integration or can be integrated
- Encrypted channel for uploading/downloading
- Supports file encryption (optional)
- Audit logs for file upload/download
- Approval workflow for when a file is uploaded to the file sharing
  server
- Firewall for access restriction from/to specific systems
- Temp links (Expiration Links) - would be great since it would allow the user to download directly to the server

Most of the solutions (egnyte, owncloud, accellion,etc) have all the features except the approval workflow which is something we need to ensure the uploader's manager is aware of the file transfer taking place and has approved the uploading.